# Interpret NodeJS Buffer in Java - byte size mismatch (Encrypting in NodeJS and Decrypting in Java)

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, byte, buffer

He folks, I'm a little novice using NodeJS and Encrypting, I'm using a, AES-256-GCM algorithm and created a couple of buffers using it.

So I'm creating the buffers in NodeJS like:

```
let iv:Buffer = _crypto.randomBytes(12)
let key = _crypto.pbkdf2Sync(masterkey, salt, iterations, keySize, algorithm)
let cipher = _crypto.createCipheriv(ALGO, key, iv);
cipher.setAutoPadding(false);
const encryptedData: Buffer = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(text, 'utf-8'), cipher.final()]);
```

After all the encryption I send that data in base64 and URI Encoded, then in Java I'm decoding it and creating a Buffer from it.

I'm creating the buffers in Java like:

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText));
int ivLength = byteBuffer.getInt();
byte[] iv = new byte[ivLength];  //This one is changing its bytes
byteBuffer.get(iv);
byte[] cipherBytes = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()]; //This one changes its representation too
byteBuffer.get(cipherBytes);
```

The issue is that the NodeJS buffers are set to like 2Byte or unsigned int, and when I check their interpretation as array it looks like this, for example:

NodeJS Buffer IV: [131,68,189,171,57,58,199,138,7,88,183,6]

And when I try to check it in Java it looks like

Java Buffer IV: [**-125**,68,**-67**,**-85**,57,58,**-57**,**-118**,7,88,**-73**,6]

So its interpreting the buffer array differently, I think it is about Byte size in Java and NodeJS, but, jumping to the question:

Am I right? Is there any way to make them work encrypting in Node and Decrypting in Java or vice versa? Is there any way to have those NodeJS Buffers stored as a 1Byte Int Array instead of 2? Or is there any way to make them work correctly? The process works the same when I encrypt in Java and decrypt in NodeJS, the Buffers are interpreted differently and it breaks everything.
Any other suggestion? Thanks in advance for your support

Answer (score 0):

The buffer in `Node.js` is a subclass of `UInt8Array` (values from 0 to 255), while in `Java`, the `byte` type represents values from -128 to 127. In order to display them the same way, you need to use a different buffer representation. For example, `Int8Array` in Node.js:

```js
const buffer = Buffer.from([131,68,189,171,57,58,199,138,7,88,183,6]);
const intArray = new Int8Array(buffer);
console.log(intArray); // [-125, 68, -67, -85, 57, 58, -57, -118, 7, 88, -73, 6]
```

Comment: But Java is interpreting it in those values, my question is, does that mean in the end that they are representing the same thing but with different interpretation? Because I was thinking that due to that interpretation issue, they represented different things, and because of that, the decrypting was failing

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, they represent the same thing, but with a different interpretation.